# Notepad++ UDL highlight line

Tags: notepad++, udl2

I'm trying to define my own user defined language in notepad++. Reason: I want to introduce coloring schemes for different logfile entries. Does anbody know if there is a way to highlight the complete line containing a specific keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **comment line** if the special keyword is at the beginning

[image: comment line]

If what you want is to know the lines with some errors, you better use the **Mark** tab of the search window with the check of `Bookmark line`.

[image: Mark]

**[Edited 28 June 2016]**

If you want a more powerful solution that fits your need exactly, you can try with the plugin *Python Scripts*.

Once the plugin installed, you can write a python script.

- Create in your script a function `highlight_preprocessor` that does the following:

  1. For each keyword you have, remove any previous highlight by calling `Editor.markerDeleteAll(<ID_keyword>)` where `<ID_keyword>` is a digit associated to the keyword (e.g. 10 for *error*, 11 for *warning*, etc.)
  2. For each `<ID_keyword>`, set the colors of the highlight (e.g. dark gray) by calling the function `editor.markerSetBack(<ID_keyword>, (<R>, <G>, <B>) )` (where the last 3 numbers are the RGB values of the color - 20/20/20 for dark grey)
  3. Parse the text of your document and for each line matching a keyword, call the function `editor.markerAdd(<line_number>, <ID_keyword>)`
- Call the function each time the file is saved by putting this line at the end of your script `notepad.callback(highlight_preprocessor, [NOTIFICATION.FILEBEFORESAVE])`

Takes some time and effort to make it work but at least it is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately the keywords are not at the beginning of the logline.

Comment: OK, but at least the words and what's following would be high-lighted. Another simple alternative is to bookmark some specific lines (like the ones with error). If you want a more powerful solution, you can try with Python Scipt (I have updated my solution).

Answer (score 2):

use ((EOL)) in close: so that it highlights till the end of the line with a specific keyword.